# SDL window isn't showing on Cygwin

Tags: c++, cygwin, sdl-2

I am trying to run an SDL application with very basic code on Cygwin, but I have the following error after calling `SDL_Init`:

```
No available video device
```

I have X11 packages installed, but that isn't solving the issue

Comment: Just install Xming and run it. You need an X server which Windows does not provide while on Unix entire UI is done on X server. You will not even need to set DISPLAY if you have just one instance of X server is running which is typically localhost:0.0. Note that it is possible to run several X servers and you can spawn separate copies of your application on those individually.

Answer (score 3):

You need to start the X server and set the `DISPLAY` variable appropriately before running an X program.

Comment: I've done that and `export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0` but no results, btw, when I start X server, a window which is all black is displayed